# How to remove item from twig cache with it's key

Tags: php, symfony

I use the twig cache tag in Symfony.

As described in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/cache.html), I use an updatedAt entity property and set the cache tag like this :

```
{% "post-" ~ post.id ~ "-" ~ post.updatedAt %}
```

It's ok to handle post update, category delete or update and comment delete with an eventSubscriber that set a new updatedAt property on the post entity.

But how can I remove the cached post on post delete ?

Comment: Not sure to understand... You shoudn't access to a page with a post.id of a deleted post...

Comment: You're right, but I want to make sure cached post is deleted on post delete. I know I could a add a TTL but would prefer to do it manualy.

Comment: no need... You will never pass a delete post to your twig template...

Comment: I know. I'm just wondering if old cached post are deleted when a new cached key is given. I'm not sure of that, so I want to do it manualy.